# Call Kotlin function in Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am a neophite in Kotlin. I need to call a method in a class created in Kotlin from a Java class.
The class in question concerns the creation of the db.

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Indirizzo::class, Dispositivo::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class WppDb : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun DispositivoDao(): DispositivoDao
    abstract fun IndirizzoDao(): IndirizzoDao

    private var INSTANCE : WppDb? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): WppDb? {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(WppDb::class) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            WppDb::class.java, "weather.db")
                           .build()
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE
    }

    fun destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null
    }
}
```

I need to call the `getInstance()` method from a Java Activity.

Comment: read the docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the equivalent of what Room samples usually show with a static Java field and static getter method for it, you can place those functions in the [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) of your class:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Indirizzo::class, Dispositivo::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class WppDb : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun DispositivoDao(): DispositivoDao
    abstract fun IndirizzoDao() : IndirizzoDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE : WppDb? =  null

        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(context: Context): WppDb? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(WppDb::class) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    WppDb::class.java, "weather.db")
                                   .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }

        @JvmStatic
        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call `WppDb.getInstance(context)` from either Kotlin or Java code. Note the [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/index.html) annotations which make these calls nicer in Java - without them, you'd have to use `WppDb.Companion` to get the companion object, and then call the `getInstance` function on that (so `WppDb.Companion.getInstance(context)` altogether).

Comment: I am getting `error: INSTANCE has private access`. How to do this if there is no @JvmStatic annotation (for some other SDK and I can't change the code)?

Comment: I think there was a mistake in the answer, if you don't have `@JvmStatic` on the accessor method, your syntax would be `WppDb.Companion.getInstance(context)` in Java.